# How to use Salesforce as IDP for SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, salesforce, single-sign-on, claims-based-identity

I am looking for some step by step instructions on how to configure a SharePoint 2010 environment to use Salesforce as the IDP. So that my team site user can login and get authenticate using Salesforce.com credentials.

Answer (score -1):

This is non-trivial. That attached link has a lot of steps, and if the link is unavailable, you should consider contacting salesforce support.

The article cover "Single Sign-on using WS-Federation, which is possible through an Apex implementation, and does not require and ADFS implementation."

[Configuring SSO to sharepoint using WSFed](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Configuring-SSO-to-SharePoint)

Comment: Link only answers are highly discouraged as they tend to break. Pull the relevant portion of your link into this answer so that the information is available, even if the link is not.

Comment: I added some more information about the link, but you have to pretty much follow it step-by-step, and it is certainly non-trivial. I didn't want to paste the entire article here, since some of the instructions might change.